# Do I need .net framework 4 and MVC 4 installed on hosting server to deploy MVC 4 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

We have created a solution in MVC 4, targeting .Net framework 4. On local IIS it runs like honey. But recently I Published it and copied all my data including Bin folder ( which includes dll dependencies of my project) to hosting server. But whenever I am trying to visit my domain 
`www.myexampledomain.com/`

It returns nothing. But an error. that 
`Viewbag is not available in current context`

Why M I getting this error. I found ASP.NET Versions 1 & 2 on my hosting account. Do I need to install .Net framework  on server, if yes do I need to install MVC 4 too?

Comment: MVC is compiled into your application when you publish, but yes, you must have the required version of the .NET Framework installed on the server. I believe MVC 4 will actually run on 3.5+, but it's better to just use the latest, which is currently 4.5.2. Not relevant really, but just FYI, starting with MVC 6, installing .NET Framework on the server is no longer necessary; it bundles .NET Core into the application by default, meaning you can just drop your app and go. However, that's still in pre-release, currently.

Comment: By far... What I did is, I created application that is targeting .NET 4,using MVC 4, Then I Published It to some folder.. Then I went on my Server's panel.. Then I uploaded all the files from folder where it was published to server's httpdocs folder.. Now when I tried to access my home (index.cshtml located in Views/Home/Index.cshtml) it is preventing application from displaying error on  the error page. I am receiving following error ( Please check my comment below)

Comment: Server Error in '/new_site' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Hi, Chris , I have contacted Parallels Plesk Support Team, They said they have MVC 4 support, But I can't see any other ASP.NET version than 1,2.0. To try I have Made all dlls to copy local and published. If you have any info regarding Parallels Plesk then kindly Forward it. Thanks for helping! But I Need More !

Answer (score 1):

no need of MVC 4 to be install just install .net framework
MVC 4 is for developing application in MVC pattern and .net framework is for provide runtime environment

Comment: can You kindly give me details for how to deploy MVC 4 application to Parallels Plesk Panel.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot and after reading comments n 5-10 trails , I found I made a small mistake by not setting `CopyToLocal` property of every MVC referenced DLL to `true`. It took me 2 days to resolve.

If you have same issue. kindly check on this solution too. It might help you!